# Allow users to comment on posts, can't mass-assign post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to programming and I'm struggling with a new feature I'm implementing in my app. I want users to be able to comment on others' microposts.

I'm getting the error: cant mass assignment micropost

User Model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation #is this secure with password there?
attr_protected :admin   #attr_protected necessary?
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, :through => :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

Micropost Model:

```
attr_accessible :comment #basically the content of the post
attr_protected :user_id
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment Model:

```
attr_accessible :content, :micropost
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :micropost
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :micropost_id, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true
default_scope order: 'comments.created_at ASC'   #is this necessary?
```

Comments Controller:

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find_by_id(params[:id])   #is this necessary?
  @comment = current_user.comments.create(:micropost => @micropost)
  redirect_to :back
end
```

User Controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
  @comments = @micropost.comments
  @comment = current_user.comments.create(:micropost => @micropost) #build, new or create??
end
```

View/comments/_form:(this partial is called at the end of every micropost)

```
<span class="content"><%= @comment.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">Said <%= time_ago_in_words(@comment.created_at) %> ago.</span
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something..." if signed_in? %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :users 
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy] 
resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your attribute microposts on attr_accessible

```
attr_accessible :content, :micropost
```

By default all the attributes are inaccessible. You have to define yours accessible attributes on attr_accessible.

More information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accessible_attributes)

Comment: So that means i should removed all of the attr_protected's? Also micropost isn't part of the microposts schema. I added your suggestion but got the same problem.

Comment: I believe you have to have "attr_accessible :comment_id" on Micropost Model.

Comment: Yea it works but i'm getting some weird error now from a timestamp im using in the same file (I've updated the code) so im going to repost it as different question. thanks for your help. Ill put the link in a comment incase your interested

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626278/cant-convert-nil-into-an-exact-number

Answer (score 0):

JMarques has it right but I like to use `_id` on `attr_accessible` to keep it consistent.  With this in mind, you can use

```
 # comment.rb
 attr_accessible :content, :micropost_id

 # controller
 current_user.comments.create(:micropost_id => @micropost.try(:id))
```

Just added a `try` there just in case `find_by_id` returns `nil`

Answer (score 0):

According to rails4 you can use the strong parameters:

```
    def create
      @micropost = Micropost.find_by_id(micropost_params)
     ................

    end

   private
    def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:id)
    end
```