# can't convert nil into an exact number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want users to be able to comment on others' microposts but I keep getting the following error: can't convert nil into an exact number

It is coming from the timestamp in the View/comments/_form file below. For some reason @comment.created_at comes back as nil

View/comments/_form:(this partial is called at the end of every micropost)

```
<span class="content"><%= @comment.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">Said <%= time_ago_in_words(@comment.created_at) %> ago.</span
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something..." if signed_in? %>
<% end %>
```

User Model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation #is this secure with password there?
attr_protected :admin   #attr_protected necessary?
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, :through => :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

Micropost Model:

```
attr_accessible :comment #basically the content of the post
attr_protected :user_id
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment Model:

```
attr_accessible :content, :micropost
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :micropost
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :micropost_id, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true
default_scope order: 'comments.created_at ASC'   #is this necessary?
```

Comments Controller:

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find_by_id(params[:id])   #is this necessary?
  @comment = current_user.comments.create(:micropost => @micropost)
  redirect_to :back
end
```

User Controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
  @comments = @micropost.comments
  @comment = current_user.comments.create(:micropost => @micropost) #build, new or create??
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :users 
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy] 
resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

SQL:

"comment"=>{"content"=>"EXAMPLE"}}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'H09yZpAv5qhmT3ok5fXfnQ' LIMIT 1
  Micropost Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

`@comment` is most probably a new record which has `created_at` set to `nil`

Answer (score 0):

@micropost is not created yet

add `@micropost.save` after `@micropost  = current_user.microposts.build`

```
@micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
@micropost.save
@comments = @micropost.comments
@comment = current_user.comments.create(:micropost => @micropost)
```

Comment: If adding save after a bluid, why not calling create directly?

Comment: THis is the SQL says i want null micropost id?
"comment"=>{"content"=>"EXAMPLE"}}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'H09yZpAv5qhmT3ok5fXfnQ' LIMIT 1
  Micropost Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" IS NULL